# Role based routes in next.js in React

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am quite new to React, I got a starter kit which has next.js for authentication in React.
I want to restrict access to admin routes when a user accesses them.

I have two roles, `admin` and `user`, which gets stored in session after successful login.

The _app.jsx inside pages folder looks like this.

```
    /**
 * Custom Next.js App
 *
 * @see https://nextjs.org/docs#custom-app
 */

import React from 'react'
import Head from 'next/head'
import { NextAuth } from 'next-auth/client'
import withRedux from 'next-redux-wrapper'
import NextSeo from 'next-seo'
import App, { Container as NextContainer } from 'next/app'
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux'
import { Favicon, GTMScript, WebFonts } from '../components/head'
import { AuthUserProvider } from '../contexts/AuthUserContext'
import makeSEO from '../lib/seo'
import makeStore from '../lib/store'
// Global CSS from SCSS (compiles to style.css in _document)
import '../styles/globals.scss'

class CustomApp extends App {
  static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
    let pageProps = {}

    ctx.session = await NextAuth.init({ req: ctx.req })

    if (Component.getInitialProps) {
      pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx)
    }

    return {
      pageProps,
      seo: makeSEO(ctx.req),
      session: ctx.session,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // picturefill for <picture> and srcset support in older browsers
    // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
    if (process.browser) require('picturefill')
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, seo, session, store } = this.props

    return (
      <NextContainer>
        {
          // to keep <Head/> items de-duped we should use next/head in _app.jsx
          // @see https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6919
        }
        <Head>
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui"
          />
          <WebFonts />
          <Favicon />
          <GTMScript />
        </Head>
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
          <AuthUserProvider session={session}>
            <NextSeo config={seo} />
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </AuthUserProvider>
        </ReduxProvider>
      </NextContainer>
    )
  }
}

export default withRedux(makeStore)(CustomApp)
```

Can anyone guide me on what to do in order to make the routes accessible as per the role?

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get roles working with next-auth and [useSession](https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#usesession).  Hopefully, this helps you as well.

**models/index.js**

```js
import User, { UserSchema } from "./User"

export default {
  User: {
    model: User,
    schema: UserSchema
  }
}
```

**models/User.js**

```js
import Adapters from "next-auth/adapters"

// Extend the built-in models using class inheritance
export default class User extends Adapters.TypeORM.Models.User.model {
  constructor(name, email, image, emailVerified, roles) {
    super(name, email, image, emailVerified)
    if (roles) { this.roles = roles}
  }
}

export const UserSchema = {
  name: "User",
  target: User,
  columns: {
    ...Adapters.TypeORM.Models.User.schema.columns,
    roles: {
      type: "varchar",
      nullable: true
    },
  },
}
```

**pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js**

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers'
import Adapters from 'next-auth/adapters'

import Models from '../../../models'

export default NextAuth({
  // @link https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/providers
  providers: [
    Providers.Google({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
    })
  ],
  // @link https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/typeorm-custom-models
  adapter: Adapters.TypeORM.Adapter(
    process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    {
      models: {
        User: Models.User
      }
    }
  ),
  session: { jwt: true },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
      if (account?.accessToken) {
        token.accessToken = account.accessToken
      }
      if (user?.roles) {
        token.roles = user.roles
      }
      return token
    },
    async session(session, token) {
      if(token?.accessToken) {
        session.accessToken = token.accessToken
      }
      if (token?.roles) {
        session.user.roles = token.roles
      }
      return session
    }
  }
});
```

**Usage - in JSX**

```
{!session &&  sessionLoading && <p>Loading...</p>}
{!session && !sessionLoading && <p>Access Denied - Not logged in</p> }
{ session && !sessionLoading && !session.user?.roles?.includes("Verified") && <p>Access Denied - Unverified</p> }
{ session && !sessionLoading && session.user?.roles?.includes("Verified") && <>
  <p>Stuff for verified users</p>
  {session.user.roles && session.user.roles.includes("Admin") && <>
    <button id="doSomething">Admin Only</button>
  </>}
  <p>More stuff for verified users</p>
</>}
```

[Github Thread](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/805)

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your example! Sorry if this is a stupid question, but where exactly did you put/find the models/User.js and models/index.js? It seems like hacking away in the node_modules/next-auth/dist/adapters... folder would not be the correct approach? Thanks!

Comment: I created each of those files in the paths as listed.  There should be no reason to modify anything in node_modules and I'd suggest avoiding that approach entirely.  Please take a look at the [TypeORM Custom Models](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/typeorm-custom-models) as my example is adapted from that tutorial.

Comment: @JasonReiche, why does one need database URL? Is it possible to do the same without any database?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I have done it.

File: _app.js

```
...
const App = ({ Component, pageProps }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  const getUser = async () => {
    try {
      const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

      const user = //replace with your backend api that fetches user details with role (admin, user, etc.)

      if (user && user.data && user.success) {
        setUser(user.data);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
      switch (event) {
        case 'signIn':
          setAuth(true);
          break;
        case 'signOut':
          setAuth(false);
          break;
        case 'signIn_failure':
          setAuth(false);
          break;
      }
    });
    getUser();
  }, [isAuth]);

  Auth.currentSession()
      .then(async (currentSession) => {
        const idTokenExpireTime = currentSession.getIdToken().getExpiration();
        const currentTime = Math.round(+new Date() / 1000);

        if (idTokenExpireTime < currentTime) {
          Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
              .then((res) => {
                const { refreshToken } = res.getSignInUserSession();

                res.refreshSession(refreshToken, (err, session) => {
                  if (err) {
                    //error logic
                  } else {
                    Account.token.set(session.idToken.jwtToken);
                    Account.refreshToken.set(session.refreshToken.token);
                  }
                });
              });
        }

        store.dispatch(setIsAuth(true));
        setAuth(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        store.dispatch(setIsAuth(false));
        setAuth(false);
      });

  if (pageProps.protected && user == null)
      return (
          <div id={'globalLoader'}>
            <div className="loader">
            </div>
          </div>
      );

  if (pageProps.protected && user && pageProps.userTypes && pageProps.userTypes.indexOf(user.role) === -1)
      return <Page403 />;

  return (<Provider store={store}><Component {...pageProps} /></Provider>);

};

export default App;
```

The logic is to fetch user with role info and check it and render accordingly. If page props has related keys (protected: true, userTypes: ["Admin"]), it is going to be protected from unauthorized access.

Page.tsx

```
...
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { withSSRContext } from "aws-amplify";
...

const Page = () => {
  ...
}

export async function authenticatedUsers(context) {
    const { Auth } = withSSRContext(context);
    try {
        await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return true
    }
    return false
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {
    let shouldRedirect = await authenticatedUsers(ctx);

    if (shouldRedirect) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/sign-in',
                permanent: false
            }
        }
    }
    return {
        props: {
            protected: true,
            userTypes: ["Admin"]
        }
    }
}

export default Page;
```

This page is protected. If you do not use them like props: {}, it will not be protected and normal users will access the page.

Css file

```
#globalLoader{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1700;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    /*left: 0,*/
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
/* From uiverse.io by @satyamchaudharydev */
.loader {
    --clr: #3498db;
    /* color of spining  */
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
.loader:before, .loader:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -10px;
    left: -10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: var(--clr);
}
.loader:before {
    z-index: 100;
    animation: spin 1s infinite;
}
.loader:after {
    border: 10px solid #ccc;
}
@keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```